# Issue with duplicated values in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I would like to replace this formula with a function in VBA : `=IFERROR(INDEX(SZCategoryData!E:E,MATCH(1,('SZCategory tailored'!B$3=SZCategoryData!F:F)*('SZCategory tailored'!A12=SZCategoryData!A:A),0)),"")`

I used this function:

```
Sub BRM_ID1()
    For i = 2 To 224
        For j = 4 To 224  
            If Worksheets("SZCategoryData").Cells(i, 6).Value = "BRM_ID" Then
                Worksheets("SZCategory tailored").Cells(j, 2).Value = Worksheets("SZCategoryData").Cells(i, 5)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I have column A  ( `Task_id` ) : 1211,1211,1212,1213,1214 in my sheet `SZCategoryData` and column B ( `BRM_ID` associated to each `task id` ) that I need to copy from `SZCategoryData` to column C in another sheet `SZCategory tailored`.

Sometimes my `task Id` dosen't have an associated `brm_id` so the probleme with my code is that : it's copy values one after another without checking if it is associated to the right `task id`. For example my `task id 1212` doesn't have a `BRM_ID` associated in the column B instead of keeping the cell empty it copies the `BRM ID` of `1213` ( the next one).

Comment: Food for thought: if the conditional expression doesn't care for `j`, then why does it need to be tested 220 times? Suggestion: use meaningful names. `sourceRow` and `destinationRow` would be a thousand times clearer than `i` and `j`. Also: pull the worksheets into their own local object variables *once* instead of dereferencing them from the `Worksheets` collection every single time. `SZCategoryData` gets pulled from the collection *at least* 48,840 times... and gets you the very same object reference *every single time*.

Comment: Ok thank you. I am going to test that. Did you understand my formula ? and if there is a way to convert it in VBA ?

Comment: TBH I merely scanned through your code. Yes, there's a way. There's always a way. Can you clarify what the exacty problem is? It's hard to tell from the current problem description. See [mcve] for more details.

Comment: I have a colomun A  ( Task_id ) : 1211,1211,1212,1213,1214 and a column B ( BRM_ID associated to each task id ) sometimes my task Id dosen't have an associated brm_id so the probleme with my code is that : it's copy values on after other without checking if it is associated to the right task id. For example my task id 1212 doesn't have a BRM_ID associated in the column B instead of keeping de cells empty it copies the BRM ID of 1213 ( the next one).

Comment: I'd warmly recommend you [edit] your post to put as much useful context/information/data as you reasonably can

Comment: ok thanks I changed my post .

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me to solve the issue . Many thanks <3

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely certain I understand your code, but hopefully this will get you a bit closer to a solution. As Mat's Mug correctly noted, you need more descriptive names with your variables. This makes it far easier to understand your code. It wouldn't hurt to turn on `Option Explicit` either.

Here's the modified code:

```
Sub BRM_ID1()
    Dim SourceData As Worksheet

    ' Highly recommend not relying on ActiveWorkbook. Only using it as a qualifier since that is the current qualifier (though implicit).
    Set SourceData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SZCategoryData")

    Dim TailoredData As Worksheet
    Set TailoredData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SZCategory tailored")

    Dim SourceRow As Long
    ' You're going to run into issues with the hardcoded min and max values here.
    For SourceRow = 2 To 224
        Dim DestinationRow As Long
        ' Here as well.
        For DestinationRow = 4 To 224
            ' Note that I am assuming that you want to match the value in TailoredData.Cells(DestinatioNRow, 6).
            ' You will need to adjust this depending on where your match value is.

            If SourceData.Cells(SourceRow, 6).Value = TailoredData.Cells(DestinationRow, 6).Value Then
                TailoredData.Cells(DestinationRow, 2).Value = SourceData.Cells(SourceRow, 5)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

If I am understanding your code and problem correctly, you were having issues because your code was simply checking if the value of a cell was equal to `"BRM_ID"`. In reality, you need to be checking if the `Task_ID` of the `TailoredData` is equivalent to the `Task_ID` of the `SourceData`. I took a stab at correctly aligning this, but I have no clue where your task/brm_id's are stored. Your question said columns `A`, `B`, and `C`, but your indices (`5`, and `6`) don't align to this.

Lastly, I would strongly recommend getting your hands dirty with arrays and dictionaries. Once you get this solution running, it will work, but it won't work for long. The code is **fragile**. In other words, if one *detail* changes, the code will cease to work correctly. For example, if the length of your data changes from 224 rows to 224,000 rows you will need to fix the code to reflect this (and expect a serious increase in processing time as well).

This will get you started with learning VBA, but I would strongly recommend working on improving the code further (or, ideally, work on improving your Excel skills and avoiding VBA as much as possible so that you are only solving problems with VBA that you can't reasonably solve with the built-in functionality Excel offers).

Best of luck!